# Null pointer exception when setting text of textView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Apologies if there are any basic mistakes in my code. I am a beginner so I need a little extra help. I am getting a null pointer exception error when I try to set the text of a child element within a listView. Below is the code for the class from where I am loading the listView and I have comment in front of the line that has the error.

```
public class MainTimetableDisplay extends Activity {

    public static final String CODE = "com.liliana.maintimetabledisplay.code";
    public static final String NAME = "com.liliana.maintimetabledisplay.fullname";
    public static final String CLASS_TYPE = "com.liliana.maintimetabledisplay.lecturetype";
    public static final String LOCATION = "com.liliana.maintimetabledisplay.location";
    public static final String WEEKDAY = "com.liliana.maintimetabledisplay.weekday";
    public static final String TIME = "com.liliana.maintimetabledisplay.starttime";
    public static final String REMINDER = "com.liliana.maintimetabledisplay.endtime";

    private List<UCDModule> modulesList = new ArrayList<UCDModule>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_timetable_display);

        populateModulesList();
        populateListView();
        onClickActivityLauncher();

    }



    private void populateModulesList() {

        // TODO Populate this list with data from the DB:

        // TODO: delete these dummy values used to test the listView
        modulesList.add(new UCDModule("COMP30510", "Android Development", "Practical","Online", "Tuesday", "17:00", "19:00","No reminder"));
        modulesList.add(new UCDModule("COMP30510", "Android Development", "Lecture","Online", "Friday", "17:00", "19:00","No reminder"));
        modulesList.add(new UCDModule("COMP41090", "SQL Programming", "Lecture","B.106", "Monday", "9:00", "11:00","No reminder"));
        modulesList.add(new UCDModule("COMP41090", "SQL Programming", "Practical","B.106", "Wednesday", "9:00", "11:00","No reminder"));

    }

    private void populateListView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayAdapter<UCDModule> adapter = new MyArrayAdapter();
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_modulesDisplay);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UCDModule> {
        public MyArrayAdapter () {
            super(MainTimetableDisplay.this, R.layout.module_item, modulesList);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            // Set view in case it's null
            View elementView = convertView;
            if (elementView == null)
            {
                elementView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.module_item,parent,false);
                Log.i("INFLATING VIEW","true");
            }

            // Retrieve current module in the list
            UCDModule currentModule = modulesList.get(position);

            //Composing the textView's text strings
            String code =  currentModule.getCode();
            String lectureType;
            if(currentModule.getLectureType().equals("Lecture")){
                lectureType = "L";
            }else{
                lectureType = "P";
            }

            // TODO: add this as a value automatically stored in DB upon saving module details
            String weekDay = currentModule.getWeekDay();
            String short_weekDay = null;
            if(weekDay.equals("Monday")){
                short_weekDay = "Mon";
            } else if(weekDay.equals("Tuesday")) {
                short_weekDay = "Tue";
            } else if(weekDay.equals("Wednesday")){
                short_weekDay = "Wed";
            } else if (weekDay.equals("Thursday")) {
                short_weekDay = "Thu";
            } else if (weekDay.equals("Friday")){
                short_weekDay = "Fri";
            } else if (weekDay.equals("Saturday")){
                short_weekDay = "Sat";
            }


            String startTime = currentModule.getStartTime();
            String location = currentModule.getLocation();

            String codeAndType = code + " (" + lectureType + ")" ;

            String details = short_weekDay + " " + startTime + " " + location;

            // Fill in the view
            TextView tv_codeAndType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_moduleCode_classType);
            tv_codeAndType.setText(codeAndType); // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE
            TextView tv_details = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_module_details);
            tv_details.setText(details);

            return elementView;
        }

    }

    private void onClickActivityLauncher() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_modulesDisplay);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                        int position, long id){

                    UCDModule selectedUCDModule = modulesList.get(position);

                    String code =  selectedUCDModule.getCode();
                    String fullName = selectedUCDModule.getFullName();
                    String classType = selectedUCDModule.getLectureType();
                    String location = selectedUCDModule.getLocation();
                    String weekDay = selectedUCDModule.getWeekDay();
                    String startTime = selectedUCDModule.getStartTime();
                    String endTime = selectedUCDModule.getEndTime();
                    String time = startTime + " to " + endTime;
                    String reminder = selectedUCDModule.getReminder();

                    Intent sender = new Intent(MainTimetableDisplay.this, ShowModule.class);
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();

                    extras.putString(CODE, code);
                    extras.putString(NAME, fullName);
                    extras.putString(CLASS_TYPE, classType);
                    extras.putString(LOCATION, location);
                    extras.putString(WEEKDAY, weekDay);
                    extras.putString(TIME, time);
                    extras.putString(REMINDER, reminder);

                    sender.putExtras(extras);
                    startActivity(sender);

                }
            });
    }

    public void addModuleButton(View view){
        Intent addModuleLaunch = new Intent(MainTimetableDisplay.this,AddModule.class);
        startActivity(addModuleLaunch);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_timetable_display_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is what's displayed in my LogCat:

```
03-25 15:21:46.703: D/AndroidRuntime(438): Shutting down VM
03-25 15:21:46.703: W/dalvikvm(438): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.liliana.ucdmoduletimetable.MainTimetableDisplay$MyArrayAdapter.getView(MainTimetableDisplay.java:128)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-25 15:21:46.753: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I run the debug, I see that the textView is null, however I can't figure out why.

Thanks!

Comment: something at `MainTimetableDisplay.java:128` is pointing to null

Comment: Use `elementView` for finding Views from `module_item` row layout.like `tv_codeAndType = (TextView)elementView.findViewById(R.id.textView_moduleCode_classType);`

Comment: @donfuxx: Yes, indeed I agree. line 128 is the one I've commented in my code above: "tv_codeAndType.setText(codeAndType); // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE". And the "something" is the textView, but I don't know why.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: thanks so much! That was the problem. If you post it as an answer I'll mark it for you. Edit: saw someone did it already :-)

Comment: what Fllo answered thats the resolved answer, you are using simply findviewbyid but you need the elementView.findViewById, just for best practice write the adapter classes  in another file that extend baseadapter and use viewholders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to attach your `findViewById` method with your inflated view `elementView` like:

```
TextView tv_codeAndType = (TextView) elementView.findViewById(R.id.textView_moduleCode_classType);
```

Same for others..